# How to compare points of two different paths (array of points)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to compare the points of two different paths to see if they are similar.

My problem is, both paths have different starting points. These paths are not simple rectangles either, so I don't think I can reorder the array based on the smallest x and y values.

I have tried this :

```
function orderPoints(points) {
  var smallestX;
  var smallestY;
  var smallestIndex;

  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) { 
    if (!smallestX) { 
      smallestX = points[i].x;
      smallestIndex = i;
      smallestY = points[i].y;
    } else {
      if (points[i].x < smallestX && points[i].y < smallestY) { 
        smallestX = points[i].x;
        smallestY = points[i].y;
        smallestIndex = i;
      }
    }
  }

  //reorder array
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = smallestIndex; i < points.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(points[i])
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < smallestIndex; i++) {
    newArray.push(points[i])
  }
  //console.log(newArray)   
  return newArray;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. I know these two paths are very similar and should only end up with a very small difference. But the difference I get back looks incorrect, so I think the 'starting point' of both point arrays are wrong. Any ideas ?

Here is a JSFiddle with my current code : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/5b3646zj/

Comment: You could try recalculating both paths as if they started from 0,0 by subtracting the first point of the path from all points in the path. Then the JSON.stringify version of both paths should be the same, if they have the exact same shape.

Comment: @Shilly are you able to provide an example as I can't see how that would work as both paths have different starting points

Comment: Please define 'similar paths' more precisely. Do you want to test if path #2 is an exact translation of path #1? Or do you want to compute some kind of similarity score?

Comment: Do you want to compare the morphology *and* the size? I mean, do you want to see if they are exactly the same path or just paths with the same design but independent of the size and the rotation?

Comment: I'll try making a mockup, give me a few minutes. But as Arnauld says, this technique will only wotrk for paths that are exactly the same, but you could expand it further to indeed calculate percentage of difficulty, but that would require a bunch more code.

Comment: Basically, the problem is, do they fall on top of each other. They both have the same amount of points and are the same shape, so I thought it would just be as simple as comparing corresponding points once I know the starting point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your latest comments into account, I think this is what you need:

```js
var path1 = [
  { "x": 1.0265, "y": 2.4715 }, { "x": 5.4865, "y": 2.4715 },
  { "x": 5.5615, "y": 2.3965 }, { "x": 5.5615, "y": 0.2965 },
  { "x": 5.4865, "y": 0.2215 }, { "x": 1.0265, "y": 0.2215 },
  { "x": 0.9515, "y": 0.2965 }, { "x": 0.9515, "y": 2.3965 }
];
var path2 = [
  { "x": 5.5615, "y": 0.2965 }, { "x": 5.5615, "y": 2.3965 },
  { "x": 5.4865, "y": 2.4715 }, { "x": 1.0265, "y": 2.4715 },
  { "x": 0.9515, "y": 2.3965 }, { "x": 0.9515, "y": 0.2965 },
  { "x": 1.0265, "y": 0.2215 }, { "x": 5.4865, "y": 0.2215 }
];

function pathDifference(p1, p2) {
  // abort early if the paths have different lengths
  if(p1.length != p2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  // sort points in each path
  [ p1, p2 ].forEach(function(p) {
    p.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y) ? -1 : 1;
    });
  });

  // build array of {dx, dy} differences between the 2 paths
  return p1.map(function(p, i) {
    return { dx: p2[i].x - p.x, dy: p2[i].y - p.y };
  });
}

console.log(pathDifference(path1, path2));
```

**A note about the sort**

You can't sort the points by comparing X only (or Y only). Let's consider the following example:

```
P0 = (7, 9), P1 = (12, 3), P2 = (7, 5)
```

By comparing X coordinates, you can clearly tell that P1 is 'after' P0 and P2. But you need a second deterministic sort rule when both X coordinates are identical, so that you can decide whether P2 is before or after P0.

For instance:

```
if X0 < X1 then P0 is before P1
if X0 > X1 then P0 is after P1
if X0 == X1 AND Y0 < Y1 then P0 is before P1
if X0 == X1 AND Y0 > Y1 then P0 is after P1
```

Without the 2nd criterion, the `.sort()` method would randomly order all points that have the same X coordinate.

(Comparing X first and Y second is just a convention. Doing it the other way around would work just as well, as long as you're using the same method for both paths.)

Comment: This looks great but I think there's a slight problem in the sort. If you take a look at my fiddle and at the orderPoints function. I get the index of the smallestX value and use that to 'rebuild' the path array. Hope I explain this well, say I have an array 1,2,3,4,5 and index 3 is the point I want to start at, I reorder my array so its like so 3,4,5,1,2 as I need to keep the same order so it draws the path correctly. Does that make sense ? If you look at the console logs here : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/b97tvxc1/ the last two points need to be swapped around (i think)

Comment: @thatOneGuy I've just added a note about the sort in my answer. Please let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: I think that makes sense. Are you saying that the ordering is the same ? (i.e a different starting point but the order is the same) as I don't understand how it is kept the same if thats the case

Comment: As you can see from this example I have put together the points aren't drawn in the correct order :( : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/5b3646zj/2/

Comment: As it is, my function is sorting the _original_ paths that are passed to it. Use `pathDifference(path1.slice(), path2.slice())` if you want it to work on copies instead. This way, your original paths will remain unaltered.

Comment: the whole idea of this was to compare corresponding points by finding out at least one point on a path that is the same point in another path and go from there through the array. The only rearranging of the arrays i wish to do is changing the starting point. It should keep the same ordering

Comment: I think I see where you're going, but sorry: this is getting too far away from the original question. Getting the order of the points in path #2 compared to their order in path #1 is an entirely other question, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Just an example how one could compare identical paths with different starting points.

```
var path1 = [
        {'x' : 5, 'y' : 10},
        {'x' : 3, 'y' : 8},
        {'x' : 9, 'y' : 14},
        {'x' : 7, 'y' : 25}
    ],
    path2 = [
        {'x' : 11, 'y' : 16},
        {'x' : 9, 'y' : 14},
        {'x' : 15, 'y' : 20},
        {'x' : 13, 'y' : 31}        
    ],
    normalize = function normalize( path ) {
        var centerX = path[0].x,
            centerY = path[0].y;
        return path.map(function( point ) {
            point.x -= centerX;
            point.y -= centerY;
            return point;
        });
    },
    normalizedPath1 = normalize(path1), // [{"x":0,"y":0},{"x":-2,"y":-2},{"x":4,"y":4},{"x":2,"y":15}]
    normalizedPath2 = normalize(path2); // [{"x":0,"y":0},{"x":-2,"y":-2},{"x":4,"y":4},{"x":2,"y":15}]
console.log(JSON.stringify(normalizedPath1) === JSON.stringify(normalizedPath2)); // true
```

Comment: Apologies, I think I have explained this incorrectly. I think your code checks if its the same shape, I need it to see if it's in the same position

Comment: Euh, what do you mean? Position is where it's located on the xy grid no? Two paths only have the same position if all their points are the same and if they have the same shape. This indeed checks if they have the same shape, no matter where they start, as long as they are in the same quadrant of the xy grid. (It doesn't check for mirrored paths)

Comment: Yea but the data for your code is in order, i.e the first element in path1 corresponds to the first in path2 and so on. Mine is unordered and what I need is a way to check which x and y coordinates in path 1 correspond to which in path2. So I can then check the different in the points

Comment: Paths are always in order. Sorry I misunderstood indeed. I wrongly assumed these are coordinates and such. And walking from point A to B to C then back to A isn't the same path as walking from point A to C to B and back to A. Can you give more explanation about what these points represent? And what you mean with `check which x and y coordinates in path 1 correspond to which in path2` I ahve a feeling a solution like Arnauld agve with sorting the points might work.